# inapproriate result using sum method in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hello i am new to HQL and i stuck with a query in HQL.

**Structure of the problem**

i have two classes Project and Income in hibernate with one (project) to many(income) relationship.

there are so many incomes of a particular project.

**What i want to do?**

i want to retrieve all of the project, each with sum of its all income.
let suppose there are two projects with 3000(sum of various different incomes for project one) and 4000(sum of various different incomes for project two) total income amount and i want to retrieve them as a list of Objects. this list of the Object should contain project one and two with their individual total amount.

**What i am doing**

```
   public java.util.List<Object[]> retrieveFromTo(int firstResult, int maxResult) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery(
              "select p.projectId, "
            + "p.projectDateOfCommencement, "
            + "p.projectName, "
            + "pi.investorName, "
            + "sum(bc.incomeAmount), "
            + "sum(ab.expenseAmount), "
            + "sum(bc.incomeAmount)-sum(ab.expenseAmount), "
            + "p.projectStatus, "
            + "p.projectCompletitionDate "
            + "from Project as p, Investor as i "
                      + "left outer join p.projectExpenses as ab "
                      + "left outer join p.projectIncome as bc "
                      + "left outer join p.projectInvestor as pi "
                      + "group by p.projectId, pi.investorId "                          
                      + "order by p.projectId desc ")
            .setFirstResult(firstResult)
            .setMaxResults(maxResult);

    List<Object[]> projects = query.list();

    session.close();

    return projects;        
}
```

Result of the query is producing inappropriate result.

let suppose there are two projects and if the total incomes of both project is suppose 3000 then this query retrieve list of the project where total income of first is 3000(correct) but total income of the second project is just double of the first one that means 6000 instead it should be 3000 as well.

Please someone let me know that what exactly i want to add or remove from my query to get my desired output.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Two classes Project and Incomes and there is one(project) to many(incomes) relationship between them. i want to retrieve a list of Projects where each project should have sum of all its incomes. i have write the following given query but it is not working properly

Comment: would be more helpful if you add to your question some examples with data, executed query and results

Comment: Is the actual result a multiple of the expected result?

Comment: the output is just double of the expected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your problem, you seem to have OneToMany relationships in this manner:

```
public class Project {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    List<Expense> expenses;

    @OneToMany
    List<Income> incomes;

    ...
}
```

Lets suppose your database structure is like this;

**Project**

```
id          name 
1           helloWorld
```

**project_income**

```
proj_id     income_id
1           1
```

**project_expense**

```
proj_id     expense_id
1           1
1           2
```

**income**

```
id          amount
1           200
```

**expense**

```
id          amount
1           500
2           600
```

Your query produces result in this manner

```
proj_id     proj_name       income_id       income_amount       expense_id      expense_amount
1           helloWorld      1               200                 1               500
1           helloWorld      1               200                 2               600
```

and so when you sum `incomeAmount` and `expenseAmount`, you get a result like this:

```
proj_id     proj_name       sum(income_amount)      sum(expense_amount)
1           helloWorld      400                     1100
```

Because of this, when you sum `incomeAmount` and `expenseAmount`, you (sometimes) get double or triple values. Its the nature of join statements. You may wanna take a look as to what is inner and outer joins and how do they produce results.

To get the desired results, one (one of the many available) solution is that you can use multiple select statements as shown below:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
          "select p.projectId, "
        + "p.projectName, "
        + "(select sum(i.incomeAmount) from Income i where i.incomeProject = p), "
        + "(select sum(e.expenseAmount) from Expense e where e.expenseProject = p), "
        + "from Project as p"
                  + "group by p.projectId, pi.investorId ")
        .setFirstResult(firstResult)
        .setMaxResults(maxResult);
```

**Output:**

```
proj_id     proj_name       sum(income_amount)      sum(expense_amount)
1           helloWorld      200                     1100
```

I hope it helps.